Associating non-static data with slice in Rust
I'm trying to debug a piece of the following code:
pub mod packet {
    pub mod cmd_response {
        pub const ERR: u8 = ...;
    }
}


pub struct Packet<'a> {
    pub action: u8,
    pub payload: &'a [u8],
}

impl<'a> Packet<'a> {
    ....

    pub fn response_error(error_code: u8) -> Self {
        Self {
            action: packet::cmd_response::ERR,
            payload: &[0, error_code],
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            this is the problematic part
        }
    }
}

Essentially I'm trying to write a constructor for Packet that associates the type and the predefined payload for a specific error packet.
The issue is that Rust really dislikes the non-static / non-const argument error_code in the slice initialization. It seems ok to return a static slice, like that:
pub fn response_error_checksum() -> Self {
    Self {
        action: packet::cmd_response::ERR,
        payload: &[0, 0x76],
    }
}

I'm trying to understand what's the reasoning for this? Why associating a static is fine but as soon as there's a variable it's giving cannot return value referencing temporary value?
The reason why I'm using the slice instead of a 'real' array is because often times those packets are associated with external buffers - for example when I'm receiving data over the link and then constructing the response using the same buffer to avoid data copying as much as possible.
I was looking at associated methods for slices but did not find anything that helps here.
I also tried using 'const generics' which works, but looks pretty counterintuitive compared to passing an argument to a function.

Does this answer your question? Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable?

Did you intend to write &[0; error_code] (note the semicolon) or as you posted &[0, error_code] (with a comma)?

Also note that if you really intended to write &[0, error_code] (an array with two elements), it is better to store the array directly, and if you have a borrow just copy it.

@ChayimFriedman no, the comma was intended here - the first element of the payload shall be 0, the second shall be the error code (or it might be LE u16 value - hard to tell). The len of the payload for these packets is always 2.

@ChayimFriedman your link seems to answer it - as long as all elements of the slice are literals the slice is considered 'static' and can safely be returned from the function.
